# mysql fulltext search and special chars

Tags: mysql

I'm using php + mysql with a full text index.
I have the following contents in the field I want to search:

"Hello: it's a test!"

"Hello i am also a test!"

When I search for "hello:", it finds both rows.
But It should only find the first row - at least until I search for "hello%".
The colon seems not tot be treated as a "normal" charakter.

Comment: Why shouldn't it find "Hello: it's a test" for "hello:"? If you want the search to be case-insensitive, you have to use a binary collation for the indexed columns (ending on *_bin*)

Comment: @Konerak: But a binary collation would make the search case-*sensitive* - and ben's search is already case-insensitive. He's just looking for a way to search for words only.

Comment: Why don't you just return null if the query contains special chars?

Comment: Hi there. Sorry I wasn't very clear.
I update my question...

Comment: Can you show us your SQL statement? I have run a test in MySQL and it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This might be far to late but I can't reproduce your problem.

I have a table with your two entries:

```
Table: Test
ID Note
-- ---------
1  Hello: it's a test!
2  Hello i am also a test!
```

If I run your first search `SELECT * FROM test t WHERE Note LIKE "Hello:"` I get 0 rows in result, as expected because in this case LIKE looks for an exact match with the whole field.

If I run your second statement `SELECT * FROM test t WHERE Note LIKE "Hello:%"` I get one row back:

```
ID Note
-- ---------
1  Hello: it's a test!
```

Are you sure you have setup the table right for FULLTEXT indexing?

First of all your Table engine must be an MyISAM table. Then you need to create an index (Indices) for your column (in my case Note) of the FULLTEXT type.